# Do I need a separate backend (Express) for an Angular project if using AWS for data storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

So, I'm working on developing my first Angular project with/for a friend of mine and I have a design question before I really get started with things.

I'm going to be storing persistent data on AWS DynamoDB (login credentials, whatever else), and my question is:

Would I be wise to develop my own REST API to interact with the Amazon backend or should I just implement that logic (AWS connections) using services in Angular?

When I took the Udemy course I've  (mostly) finished, they implemented their Firebase logic using such services for storing data, but I didn't know if that was best practice for a production app or if it was just more or less being used as an example of HTTP requests and it shouldn't -really- be done that way when you're wanting to deploy things.

I could use any advice I might get, I'm wanting to start writing code this weekend and I wanted to make sure I was committing to a decoupled project in this respect if it's best practice and should be done.

The only reason I might see a difference is if I were to use PassportJS to handle login stuff (using Express) vs. rolling my own auth system using JWT?  Otherwise it seems like it might just be an extra step that might not really be necessary and would just extend development more than it really needs to be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this some more and I have realized that there's at least some point where this app may want a separate (and native) mobile backend, so decoupling is definitely the best choice here, so I'll just go ahead and do it.

Now I get to pick a UI library.